# Link não aparece sublinhado no preview das publicações no Meta

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

Ao criar um link, ele não aparece sublinhado no preview. No Meta do SOEN o sublinhado aparece. Não era para serem iguais?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mesmo não sendo o foco da pergunta, gostaria de perguntar, porque links não aparecem sublinhado também no SOpt?

Comment: Você tá falando do preview ou depois de publicado? Não consegui achar nenhum exemplo agora.

Comment: Math, depois de publicado, isso no site principal.

Comment: Eu não me lembro se foi sempre assim, mas testei agora no site principal nosso e na versão em Inglês e em nenhum dos dois aparece sublinhado nem no preview nem depois de postado. É uma boa pergunta pq só no meta é assim, mas não sei te responder :X

Comment: Sem problemas... No SOen parece que já tentaram implementar uma vez ([veja](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271977/1608936)). Nessa [outra postagem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326004/1608936) mais recente, é feito um debate semelhante sobre. Acho que deve ser algo relacionado a UX, depois vou perguntar ao Gabe só para confirmar. Obrigado mesmo assim. :)